ReferenceError: React is not defined vite

My project needs these plugins in vite config [wasm(),nodePolyfills(),topLevelAwait()], but if I use these plugins I am getting ReferenceError: React is not defined error and it is asking me to import react in every file
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
I tried this but not helpful

What do you mean by "it is asking me to import react in every file"? For every tsx or jsx file, it's required to import React.
